# MongoDB Java Driver creating Database and Collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

i was testing how to create  database and collection mongo java driver.

```
  MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        DB db = client.getDB("ow");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("documents");
        collection.save(new BasicDBObject("_id",1));
        collection.remove(new BasicDBObject("_id",1));
        boolean result = db.collectionExists("documents");
        assertTrue(result);
        assertNotNull(collection);
        client.close();
```

I would prefer to use createCollection method on the DB object, but found that it does not create database / collection unless the first document is inserted.

My question is is this understanding correct ? Is above code correct was of creating collection or database.

Answer (score 5):

> *prefer to use createCollection method on the DB object, but found that it does not create database / collection unless the first
>   document is inserted.*

`MongoDB` creates a collection `implicitly` when the first document is saved into a collection. The `createCollection()` method explicitly creates a collection only and only **if** an options object is passed to it as an argument.

Now this makes sense. The `options` parameter can take in one or more arguments to decide the characteristics of the collection  we want to create such as `capped`,`autoIndexId`,`size`,`usePowerOf2Sizes`,`max no. of documents`.

If we do not specify any of these options, the default behavior would take precedence, i.e create a collection lazily whenever the first insert is made, with default settings.

So if we want a collection whose characteristics we are going to define, then we can pass these characteristics as a `DBObject` to the `createCollections()` method and our collection would be created. Below is an example of how to pass the options.

```
BasicDBObject options =  new BasicDBObject();
options.put("size", 12121212);
db.createCollection("hello", options);
```

> *Is above code correct was of creating collection or database.*

Yes. It allows `mongodb` to apply the `default configuration` for your collection. Unless you want to set the 
`max`,`size`,`autoIndexId`,`capped`,`usePowerOf2Sizes` properties for your new collection, this is fine.

**Refer**: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

Comment: Thanks. Concern is after createCollection method before we insert any document in mongo, show dbs does not display the db / collection, which means that creation collection which does not have any document before hand does not make any sense. right ?

Comment: Yes. `MongoDB` need not create an empty collection without knowing if the client is going to use it at all. If it did it would have been a overhead. But when the client specifically requests for a collection with options, then it does create the collection.