# Dynamically create database in mongodb in java

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Is there any way to dynamically create a new database in mongo using the 3.x Java driver along with adding a user with defined roles to it?

Comment: I don't think its supported through java drivers. You should use mongo shell for this purpose.

Comment: I have read in few answers that it could be lazily created but those were using DBObject

Comment: Please add examples and I'll be happy to help you convert them to 3 x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26952982/5829549 check this